# I am trying to extract the keywords and the count from many pdfs in the directory

Tags: r

I created a function to search for specific keywords as well as the count from multiple pdfs in the directory.

```
library(pdfsearch)
library(pdftools)
library(dplyr)

directory <- system.file('pdf','../pdfs', package = 'pdfsearch')

result <- keyword_directory(directory,
                            keyword = c('risk','upside','downside'),
                            surround_lines = 1, full_names = TRUE)
head(result)
```

The code works, but it only shows zero output

```
[1] ID       pdf_name
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

DO not use system.file, that only reads the files, you can use the following,

```
directory<-"/Users/Documents/Personal/Consultancy 2020/IMF-2020/staff-reports/"

result<-keyword_directory(directory,
                       keyword=c('The staff', "encourages"),
                       full_names=TRUE, remove_hyphen = TRUE, surround_lines=1)
```